# HTML: Split list in multiple Columns

Tags: html, list, multiple-columns

While there are many questions like that, none of them describes my problem:
I have this list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Burger</li>
  <li>Fries</li>
  <li>Coke</li>
</ul>
```

The list gets it's data from a database, that also includes the prices.

Now I need a list that also can show me the price in another column, like:

```
1. Burger    |  6.99$
2. Fries     |  2.99$
3. Coke      |  1.99$
```

But all questions I find are about multiple columns if the list is too long.

Is there a way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists aren't designed like that, I guess you could implement some kind of hacky way to make a multi-column list, or you can use a table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Burger</td>
    <td>$6.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fries</td>
    <td>$2.99</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Coke</td>
    <td>$1.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```